# npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I am install browserSync `npm install browser-sync`

but have a problem `npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6`

What is this error and how it can be solved ?

gulp  does not start

P.S: It worked before . Already 2 project so created. clear cache - not help

Comment: I get this same error when installing React Native

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hi fsevents is an API available only on OSX. So if you're using another OS like Windows as do I. Normally software that wants to use fsevents will provide an alternative or make it optional as your message reads. To my knowledge it will not stop gulp from running. I hope this can at least solve your problem or help you towards a solution.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?