# Ansible and npm install fails with "rc -9". What does this mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, ansible

We have a vagrant virtual box and want to let Ansible do some installing work. So far, setting up vagrant and ssh stuff works. Cloning git-repository - works! Other tasks tested... work!

But then we run into an issue when trying to install **npm**-dependencies. All we got is a cryptic error-message, indication an error code of "rc=-9".

When running "**npm install**" at the same virtual box via ssh everything works like a breeze. Does anyone know, what could be the problem here? Or give us a hint what error -9 could be? We are literally tapping in the dark here...

Ansible fails and returns:

`failed: [192.168.10.15] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/npm install", "failed": true, "rc": -9}`

The Ansible-playbook

```
---
- hosts: build
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root

  vars:
    working_dir: /home/vagrant/build

  tasks:
  - name: remove old working dir
    file: path={{ working_dir }} state=absent

  - name: GIT | checkout webviews repository
    become: yes
    become_user: vagrant
    git: repo=ssh://git@git.mygit.com/hello.git
         dest=/home/vagrant/build
         accept_hostkey=yes

  - name: NPM | Install gulp
    npm: name=gulp global=yes state=present

  - name: NPM | Install webviews dependencies
    npm: path=/home/vagrant/build
```

Answer (score 2):

We made some steps, that worked. Instead of using UbuntuLTS on the virtual box, we switched to Archlinux. And that returned now a human readable error-message:

```
TASK: [NPM | Install webviews dependencies] ***********************************
failed: [192.168.10.25] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/npm install", "failed": true, "rc": -9}
stderr: npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6


FATAL: all hosts have already failed — aborting
```

That last error could be resolved by using StackOverflow: [npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228862/npm-warn-optional-dep-failed-continuing-fsevents0-3-6)

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that there was not enough RAM for `npm ci` or `npm install`, and OOM has killed the process. See system log in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messaged`. It often requires 2+ GB.