# Failed to install dependencies when npm install hexo-cli -g

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, hexo

when I run `npm install hexo-cli -g` in git bash terminal in my computer, I experience a network proxy issue as shown by image below:

[code in the git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CKp.png)

Comment: I think this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228862/npm-warn-optional-dep-failed-continuing-fsevents0-3-6

Comment: the use of image to show your problem is nice but give a nice description to it so one reading your question can identify the problem before need to load external image and read it.

Comment: @comoss,  the issue not related, the error is, in fact related to network proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your computer is behind a proxy/firewall. If you configure the proxy correctly it might work. Try this:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Don´t forget to change `proxy.company.com:8080` with values from your proxy (you can find it in your Internet Explorer network configuration). More information can be found [here](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy)

If this don´t help, please, provide us the `npm-debug.log` file.